# How to build a flow using groovy script or Java SDK programmatically in mule 4

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

I had a problem with creating flow programmatically at runtime on mule 4. (so that when a user calls a endpoint, a new flow can be created and started).
Currently, I can use scripting module (groovy engine) to invoke a pre-defined and registered flow using:

```
    <scripting:execute engine="groovy" doc:name="Execute" doc:id="407d7b9e-b3f3-44c3-a02f-56a06143ac84">
        <scripting:code>
            flow = registry.lookupByName("connect").get();
            if (flow.isStarted())
                flow.stop()
            else 
                flow.start()
        </scripting:code>
    </scripting:execute>
```

I tried to build a flow. There is a method in org.mule.runtime.core API:

```
        <scripting:code>
            import org.mule.runtime.core.api.construct.Flow;
            flow = Flow.builder("newFlow", muleContext).build();
            flow.start();
        </scripting:code>
```

But `muleContext` was deprecated in org.mule.runtime.core, so this does not work. I have not found any alternative method that can construct a new flow dynamically. Could anyone help me with this or tell me whether there are alternative ways of building a flow programmatically?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, why do you want to create a flow dynamically?

Comment: Hi, I want to build a multi-tenant service using mule 4. When the users call the REST API that I built and give info about the source and destination systems, a flow will be triggered and started, which should fetch data from source system to destination system according to the schedule specified by API caller. ( a scheduler will be source component of the flow). But the problem is, different users want to specify different source&dest systems and schedules, so what I want is when different users call my service(API), a new flow can be created and started without restarting my app.

Comment: Have you considered using dynamically configured connectors instead?